# azure, ec2 or dedicated hosting

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, dedicated-server

for a scalable high traffic web site (asp.net) which platform is more powerful with minimum price ?

amazon ec2, microsoft azure or using dedicated servers,..please share your advances.

Best Regards,
sirmak

Comment: Performant is not a word

Answer (score 1):

Raw performance wise you can't beat dedicated servers (in my opinion).  Thats not to say EC2 and Azure don't have there place as they make it very easy and affordable to SCALE which is probably more applicable for high traffic websites.

For the data side this is very dependent on your data and again speaks more the to scale argument than raw performance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your solution and how it is used.

You would have to look at the amount of data you store, the amount you transfer and your compute requirements. Then estimate your costs against the price list of the suppliers.

Generally speaking dedicated servers will come out more expensive since they cost more to maintain. This may however be cheaper than moving an existing app to the cloud.